# R date variable operation

Tags: r, date, variables

I have a string/character variable contains a calendar date, eg,

x <- "2018-10-31"

I also have a variable y contains time, say 200 days.

y <- 200

How do I find out the calendar date for x + y?

I am not familiar with date type in R and struggle with how to approach this.

An add-on question, would this calculation be different if y = 4.3 months? Of course I can convert this into days, though wonder if there is more direct way to handle months without converting.

Answer (score 1):

You could utilise the `lubridate` package, which is specifically designed for handling date time data.

```
library(lubridate)
x <- ymd("2018-10-31")
x + days(200)
[1] "2019-05-19"
```

lubridate works with 'period' objects, which require integers, so you would need to convert "4.3" months into something interpretable beforehand. "4.3" doesn't mean anything concrete in terms of date-time calculation anyways.

Comment: That's great. I will explore lubricate package. And just  need to add a step to convert month variable. In our case the data is more meaningful in months as it is part of direct output from another software, to predict time to outcome in terms of months. I think we have a standard formula to convert in days.